# How to initialize data from local storage in redux-toolkit using in next.js project?

Tags: reactjs, next.js, redux-toolkit

I'm getting "ReferenceError: localStorage is not defined

This error happened while generating the page. Any console logs will be displayed in the terminal window." Error while I'm trying to access data from local storage. How can I solve this problem? Here is my code:

```
import { createSlice } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";

const initialIsAuthenticated =
  localStorage.getItem("isAuthenticated") != null
    ? JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("isAuthenticated"))
    : null;

const initialToken =
  localStorage.getItem("token") != null
    ? JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("token"))
    : null;

const initialType =
  localStorage.getItem("type") != null
    ? JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("type"))
    : null;

const initialBilkentId =
  localStorage.getItem("bilkentId") != null
    ? JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("bilkentId"))
    : null;

const initialAuthState = {
  isAuthenticated: initialIsAuthenticated,
  token: initialToken,
  type: initialType,
  bilkentId: initialBilkentId,
};

const setItemFunc = (isAuthenticated, token, type, bilkentId) => {
  localStorage.setItem("isAuthenticated", JSON.stringify(isAuthenticated));
  localStorage.setItem("token", JSON.stringify(token));
  localStorage.setItem("type", JSON.stringify(type));
  localStorage.setItem("bilkentId", JSON.stringify(bilkentId));
};

const removeItem = () => {
  localStorage.removeItem("isAuthenticated");
  localStorage.removeItem("token");
  localStorage.removeItem("type");
  localStorage.removeItem("bilkentId");
};

const authSlice = createSlice({
  name: "authentication",
  initialState: initialAuthState,
  reducers: {
    login(state, action) {
      state.isAuthenticated = true;
      state.token = action.payload.token;
      state.type = action.payload.type;
      state.bilkentId = action.payload.bilkentId;

      setItemFunc(
        state.isAuthenticated,
        state.token,
        state.type,
        state.bilkentId
      );
    },
    logout(state) {
      state.isAuthenticated = false;
      state.token = null;
      state.type = null;
      state.bilkentId = null;

      removeItem();
    },
  },
});

export const authActions = authSlice.actions;

export default authSlice.reducer;
```

[Problem screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HQ0DB.png)

I was trying to get data from local storage while using redux-toolkit.

Comment: can i ask why you're not using `redux-persist` which actually does all this for you?

Comment: Anyway using nextjs, the only way i know about is doing everything inside a `useEffect` or other related hooks, maybe in your own custom hook to use somewhere or directly inside your Root component or wherever it's needed. Since otherwise in the nodejs environment where nextjs renders the page, localStorage does not exist yet executed at global level.

Comment: @unhackit I thought it was too complex to handle; I should learn it then... Thanks

Answer (score 0):

With Redux toolkit in a Next.js project if you need [localStorage I recommend you `redux-persist`](https://github.com/rt2zz/redux-persist) especially with your need where you want to update an entire slice of state.

You can use the `persistReducer`, which allows you to specify which slices of state that should be persisted inside the local storage.

```
import { configureStore, getDefaultMiddleware } from '@reduxjs/toolkit'
import { persistReducer } from 'redux-persist'
import storage from 'redux-persist/lib/storage'

import rootReducer from './reducers'

const persistConfig = {
  key: 'root',
  storage,
  whitelist: [authSlice.name]
}

const persistedReducer = persistReducer(persistConfig, rootReducer)

const store = configureStore({
  reducer: persistedReducer,
  middleware: getDefaultMiddleware()
})

export default store
```

Moreover you are using [`localStorage` inside **reducer** and reducers should be **pure**.](https://redux.js.org/understanding/thinking-in-redux/three-principles)